# CancellationToken doesn't get triggered in the Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-functions

I've got this simple Azure Function:

```
public static class MyCounter
{
    public static int _timerRound = 0;
    public static bool _isFirst = true;

    [FunctionName("Counter")]
    //[TimeoutAttribute("00:00:05")]
    public async static Task Run([TimerTrigger("*/10 * * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log, CancellationToken token)
    {
        try
        {
            log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.UtcNow}");
            if (_isFirst)
            {
                log.Info("Cancellation token registered");
                token.Register(async () =>
                {
                    log.Info("Cancellation token requested");
                    return;
                });
                _isFirst = false;
            }
            Interlocked.Increment(ref _timerRound);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                log.Info($"Round: {_timerRound}, Step: {i}, cancel request:{token.IsCancellationRequested}");
                await Task.Delay(500, token).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("hold on, exception!", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is capturing the CancellationToken request event when the app stops or a code redeploy happened (host shutdown event).

BTW, I've also tried to check the IsCancellationRequested property in the for loop as well. Never turns true.

The main requirement is not to loose any operation/data during the function deployments, I want to know that the app is being stopped so that I persist some data to be processed once host started again after update.

Comment: Mind sharing your exact flow? Are you just triggering a shutdown from code deployment? When you say when the app stops, what kind of application stop are you referring to? Also, keep in mind that the logger instance given to you has a limited lifetime scope, scoped to the function invocation. So holding on to that instance in a static will not work as expected, so it isn't a reliable way to detect whether the token was signaled.

Comment: I'm doing a POC on updating the app so there is no production code yet to show. What I'm trying to do is to persist some data quickly(in a queue) and get out of my function before the app gets stopped. So that I can make sure that I'm not loosing any data/operation because of the app redeployment.(which leads to an app shutdown).
As I mentioned even if I check the IsCancellationRequested in the function it doesn't turn true.

Comment: Can this be done in PowerShell? If yes could you please share an example?

Answer (score 3):

Based on your code, I tested it on my side, here are my test result:

[image]

[image]

From the above screenshots, we could find that the subsequent rounds could not handle the cancellation callback except the first round. As Fabio Cavalcante commented, I removed the `_isFirst` logical checking and found it could work for all rounds as follows:

[image]

**Note:** I simulated the shutdown of my host by disabling my function when the TimerTrigger is triggered.

Comment: Thanks mate, I figure my main problem was the default stopping_wait_time in the setting.job file. increased it to 120 which is meant to be 2mins. started getting the right logs but it's intermittent. sometimes works sometimes not!

Comment: @bruce This is working for me. I would like to see if there is a way why the function has been canceled? Can we get more details?