# Does a running Azure Function complete or terminated when you publish a new version?

Tags: c#, azure-functions

Does anyone know What happens to a currently running Azure Function (.NET Core) if you Publish at the same time as it is running:

Does it:
1. Complete its work and first run with the updated code next time
2. Gets terminated in the middle of the run?
3. Something else?

My guess is 1 but countless Google search leave me without answer :-(

Answer (score 2):

When you publish, the underlying host (Azure) will restart. 
You can use a `CancellationToken` as parameter in order to get signaled when this happens and stop your work or cancel a wait for an external service.

```
    public async static Task Run([TimerTrigger("*/10 * * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, CancellationToken token)
    {
      // some function code...
    }
```

You can find a more detailed sample in this post:
[CancellationToken doesn't get triggered in the Azure Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45746876/cancellationtoken-doesnt-get-triggered-in-the-azure-functions)

Comment: Not sure I understand the answer. An Azure Function by default do not have a cancellation token so what happens in such a situation?

Comment: Just add a CancellationToken in the signature of your method. The runtime will recognize it and send you a CancellationToken instance which signals you on runtime restart / shutdown. This is fully optional and not contained in the default function template. You can add it if you need it.

You can read more about that here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#cancellation-tokens